# sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm not updating data after updating Model

Tags: sapui5

I have a form in sapui5, with empty entries and binded it with a model.

then a have a button "add data", when i press it I am setting some data to the model, which should papulate the form.

But it is not updating the form entries.

//I have console the form model after setting data - which has the new data too.

here is my code - [link](http://jsbin.com/keloyamoda/edit?html,output)

please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that (for some reason I do not know) the binding context is set wrong. So the controls try to get their values from a wrong path on the model. You can counter that by binding your controls to an absolute path by adding a `/` at the beginnin of the binding path:

```js
new sap.m.Input({value:"{/ID}",width:"40%",editable : false}),
new sap.m.Input({value:"{/name}",width:"40%",editable : true}),
new sap.m.CheckBox({selected:"{/active}"}),
```

Comment: yeah I can see it now, that is a strange thing right.... breaking my head for a long time.. thank you